# Fancybox is loading href outside of Page

Tags: jquery, fancybox

All,
I've got the following code to load a page in Fancybox:

```
$("#display_songs").fancybox({
    'href'      : 'my_page.php',
    'autoScale' : true,
});
```

This loads my page fine now but this page pulls some data from my database and loads divs based on how many rows. If I have a lot of data Fancybox goes past my current viewport on my page. I'd like to allow Fancybox to display the pop up box in the viewport and add scroll bars to it so the user can scroll that way. How can I do that?

I also tried to make my content an iframe but then it doesn't autosize my iframe:

```
$("#display_songs").fancybox({
    'type' : 'iframe',
    'href' : 'my_page.php',
});
```

**EDIT**: I guess I could probably set the width and height but I don't want it that big if the content is only like 300 X 300.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the Fancybox "AJAX" load functionality rather than the IFRAME functionality (which would give you scrollbars).

You didn't specify if you're using Fancybox 1 or 2, but in 1, you'd initialize IFRAME like this:

```
 $("#display_songs").fancybox({
 'href'      : 'my_page.php',
 'autoScale' : true,
 'type'      : 'iframe'
 });
```

Comment: I just updated my question. I tried that but it doesn't autoscale the iframe size to basically span the viewport height.

Comment: Actually for IFRAME, I would drop autoScale altogether.